# Restructuring data in Laravel eloquent from single MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have some sample data in a single MySQL table, which has fields `schedule_id, day_number, staff_id, shift_start_time, shift_end_time, hours_worked`.

I'm still relatively inexperienced when it comes to MVC and Laravel development, so I'm looking for some guidance on how to best solve this issue.

What I need to do is display the data in a table such that it is formatted similar to below:-

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
  <tr>
    <th>Staff ID</th>
    <th>Day 0</th>
    <th>Day 1</th>
    <th>Day 2</th>
    <th>Day 3</th>
    <th>Day 4</th>
    <th>Day 5</th>
  <th>Day 6</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 17:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 19:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 13:00:00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 15:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 17:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 16:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>11:00:00 - 19:00:00</td>
    <td>11:00:00 - 13:00:00</td>
    <td>10:00:00 - 15:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 17:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 16:00:00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>11:00:00 - 19:00:00</td>
    <td>11:00:00 - 13:00:00</td>
    <td>10:00:00 - 15:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 17:00:00</td>
    <td>12:00:00 - 16:00:00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My understanding is that any data transformation or filtering should take place in the models (in line with keeping the controllers slim). My first attempt at this was to retrieve all the data and start writing `@foreach` and `@while` loops in the blade template, but this lead to a mess of code and is unmaintainable and difficult to modify for future purposes.

In terms of best practices, what should I be looking to do? Some of the options I considered were to create another table, which might allow me flexibility in the future, at the cost of complexity right now.

The other option I considered was to use Eloquent's built in methods for `groupBy()` on the `staff_id` first, and create an associative array with the data in the format similar to what I need to build in my blade template.

Comment: Just a bit of criticism. If `hours_worked` is simply calculated based on shiftend - shiftstart  then it shouldn't be a column in your table as it can lead to update anomalies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database query `groupBy` probably won't do what you need. I will assume that you have a "Staff" table and this table you're showing in the question is a relationship with that table. I'm also assuming you have a model of the staff and associated relationship defined. The idea is to collect the staff members and their associated schedule entries and write them out in a table.

In the controller (or anywhere you get the data in):

```
 $staffData = Staff::with([ "schedule" => function ($query) {
      $query->orderBy("day_number");       
 }])->get();
 $dayCount = $staffData->reduce(function($result, $staff) {
        return (is_null($result) || $staff->schedule->max("day_number") > $result) ? $staff->schedule->max("day_number") : $result;
    });
 return view("theview", compact("staffData","dayCount"));
```

In the view:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
    <tr>
       <th>Staff ID</th>
       @for ($i = 0;$i < $dayCount;$i++) 
           <th>Day {{$i}}</th>
       @endfor
   </tr>

   @foreach ($staffData as $staffEntry) 
        <tr> 
            <td>{{$staffEntry->id}}</td>
            @for ($i = 0;$i < $dayCount;$i++)
                @php $dayEntry = $staffEntry->schedule->where("day_number",$i)->first(); @endphp   
                <td>{{$dayEntry?$dayEntry->shift_start_time:""}}-{{$dayEntry?$dayEntry->shift_end_time:""}}</td>
            @endfor
        </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: At the moment, I have a single table with all that data as described in the very top of my question. Should the first aim be to setup this new staff table and create the relationship to the original table?

Comment: Yes, usually you set up entities before relationships and the table you have looks like a relationship table.